# Git submodule status - how to show current branches in submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

Checking status of submodules in main repository with this command:

```
git submodule status
```

produces output (without clear information about branches):

```
491e03096e2234dab9a9533da714fb6eff5dcaa7 vendor/submodule1 (v1.51.0-560-g491e030)
8bccab48338219e73c3118ad71c8c98fbd32a4be vendor/submodule2 (v1.32.0-516-g8bccab4)
```

**Is it possible to check current branches on submodules without:**

```
cd vendor/submodule1
git status
cd ../submodule2
git status
```

**?**

This command don't work:

```
git submodule status -b
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Answer was hidden in `git submodule foreach`:

```
git submodule foreach 'git status'
```

You can always make it simpler by assign this to alias:

```
git config --global alias.sb "submodule foreach \"git status\""
```

Now `git sb` give you nice information about your branches in submodules:

```
Entering 'vendor/submodule1'
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
Entering 'vendor/submodule2'
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Answer (score 13):

You can run `git submodule status --recursive`.

It gives

- commit id
- path of the submodule in the project
- branch name

Comment: I don't think this displays the branch the submodule is on